# There is no DropDownMenuItems on my DropDownButton

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I`m just new to Flutter and Dart. Today I got some problems with DropDownButton.

I want to display item from php(it encodes as json), but there is nothing.

My php shows this things.

```json
[[{"ProductID":"3","ProductName":"test"},{"ProductID":"4","ProductName":"test1"}]]
```

and this is variety and getting data from php

```dart
    List<Map<String, String>> customerData = [];
    String _mySelection='';

    Future<String> getCustomerData() async 
    {
    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://172.30.1.6/product.php'));
    var resBody = json.decode(res.body);

    List<Map<String, String>> _mapCustomer = resBody;
    //List<String> customerlist = _mapCustomer[''];

    customerData = _mapCustomer;

    return resBody;
    }
```

this is DropDownButton source

```dart
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body : SingleChildScrollView(
            child:Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 70.0,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: new DropdownButton<String>(
                        value: _mySelection,
                        items: customerData.map((Map<String, String> product) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: product["ProductName"],
                            child: new Text(product["ProductName"]!)
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _mySelection = newValue!;
                          });
                        },
                        hint: Text('ProductName'),
                      )
                    )
              ]
            )
        )
    );
```

This is result

[image]

I`m so sorry for my poor code. How can i fix it?

Comment: if you get data from API and display it into the dropdown refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/68464115/11818376